# How to output whitespace from a SALT state that calls a script, using Jinja

Tags: jinja2, whitespace, salt-stack

I'm writing a shell script that's going to run on a number of different servers so I'm trying to run it using our SALT environment. I have it pretty much fully working, but the State output seems to be ignoring all the whitespace from my script (I'm calling the shell script from my state). This is what the state file looks like:

```
{% set theRepo = salt['grains.get']('the_repo-redacted') %}
{% set rootSls = ... redacted ... %}
{% set map = theRepo + '/directory/to/jinja' %}
{% from map import data with context %}

run command that calls my script:
  cmd.script:
    - name: salt://{{ theRepo }}/directory/to/myScript.sh
```

And the script is just a Bash shell script (which outputs correctly when running from the command line). For example, a line in my script is:

```
echo "Red       Blue       Green"
```

is printing on the SALT output as:

```
Red Blue Green
```

I tried using tabs (/t) with printf in my script but that doesn't work either. My understanding of SALT/Jinja is pretty hazy so I'm struggling with this. I did find this doc which has an entry for whitespace with Jinja https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.append ("ignore_whitespace = True/False") but I'm not sure where to put that. Would it just be an attribute in the state like this?

```
{% set ignore_whitespace = False %}
```

Thanks for any help! Sorry if this is unclear, let me know if you have any questions though and I'd be happy to clear it up.

Comment: What do you get if you just run the script with `salt-call state.single cmd.script salt://.../myScript.sh`? It includes the whitespace in the output for me.

Comment: `ignore_whitespace` is an argument for the `file.append` state, which you are not using.

Comment: @OrangeDog would that go in the state file, under the name attribute?

Comment: No, neither go there. Nothing about your sls file is likely to be affecting the output.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this, when I run the script itself it does output the whitespace. It's only the output from when I apply the actual state, which is why I was thinking it might be something in the sls

Comment: That's why I'm asking what the single state output is.

Comment: I would call that command on the command line? Sorry I'm still wrapping my head around Salt lol, trying to learning as much as I can though

Comment: Yes. `salt-call` is a CLI tool.

Comment: To answer the question, you can't output from a state using jinja, because that's not how Salt works.